# Eclipse web.xml "The error was detected when validating the file jakartaee_10.xsd"

Tags: eclipse, servlets, web.xml

Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/C:/Program Files/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas_1.2.500.v202302261818.jar!/dtdsAndSchemas/jakartaee_10.xsd) was the error thrown when running the deployment descriptor for my servlet program.

here is the description of it in the problems section:
The error was detected when validating the file "jakartaee_10.xsd" via the file "web.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "jakartaee_10.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when jakartaee_10.xsd is validated in the context of web.xml.

here is my auto generated web.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="6.0">
  <display-name>JSP_A_I</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Expecting a possible fix for this bug.